# wsDualHttpBinding not sending request to server

Tags: c#, wcf

i'm currently working on a client/server program which is using `wshttpdualbinding` for communication in vs with c#. So i'm calling webservices over this binding from the server.

Everything worked fine, but in the last days i'm encountering the following problem: if i call a service from the server, the client just stops working and stops reacting. Nothing gets send from the client.

I can't post much, because it is a big project, but i'll try to post the best snippets:

binding:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" closeTimeout="03:10:00"
      openTimeout="03:10:00" receiveTimeout="03:10:00" sendTimeout="03:10:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true"  allowCookies="false" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_Service" closeTimeout="03:10:00"
      openTimeout="03:10:00" receiveTimeout="03:10:00" sendTimeout="03:10:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true"  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

problem causing code:

```
Clusterrationalemapping cr = new Clusterrationalemapping
{
    Textbricks = rationale,
    Cluster = cluster,
    Project = CurrentProject
};
var clusterrationaleId = 0;
if (cluster.AddClusterRationaleMapping(cr))
{                                
    clusterrationaleId = _service.SaveItem(cr);
    cr.Id = clusterrationaleId;
    if(rationale.Clusterrationalemappings == null) rationale.Clusterrationalemappings = new List<Clusterrationalemapping>();
    rationale.Clusterrationalemappings.Add(cr);
}
```

A function gets called which creates a new `clusterrationalemapping` for a specific cluster. The `rational` and `CurrentProject` variables are always the same. just cluster is different.
Most of the time everything works and `service.SaveItem` returns the new Id as expected. But for one special cluster it is not working. `service.SaveItem` just stops and freezes the tool until i get some exception (server did not respond in time/gave no answer).

I'm sure that the `wsDualHttpBinding` is set correctly. If i comment out the line `Project = CurrentProject` and replace it with `Project = new Project();` everything  works fine for this cluster again.

So it looks like `clusterrationalmapping` might get too big for sending. But the exception is not saying that. And i got it from the server - from that direction it worked.

I used Microsoft Service Trace Viewer for debugging purpose and i can see there, that it instantly throws an exception that the endpoint could not be reached. So i'm pretty sure that the service dies when serializing the object.

Is there any way to debug into the service to see when exactly, or better why, it fails?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not been able to find a solution -  I still think that there has been a problem with the serializer and a too big/nested class, i changed the binding to nettcp and it is working now.